# Angular ng-packgr for angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am converting an existing angular application to library. For the same I did all the necessary changes including all the dependcies.
Now while running `ng build` for library, I am facing error

> Cannot find builder **"@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr".**

I believe the angular version 8 is not supporting `ng-packagr` version 4.7.1 ( I tried with multiple versions though).

Can anyone please help me to find the right version of `ng-packagr` ?

Comment: Have you added it as a dev dependency, i.e. npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular? Or just running npm update

Comment: yes I did but it didn't worked.  @DanielG in library project do I need to add all the dependencies in package.json(under library project) in peer dependencies also ?